# How to connect Azure Paas Database using Powershell with intergrated security

Tags: powershell, azure, authentication, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

How can I connect to an Azure SQLDatabase (Paas Instance) using Powershell without a username & password but rather with Active Directory. I can connect with a username and password when I use `invoke-sqlcmd`  as below

```
$Servername = "XXXXXX.database.windows.net"
$params = @{

   Database = $databasename

   ServerInstance = $ServerName

   Username = $UserName

   Password = $password

   'OutputSqlErrors' = $true

   Query = $QueryString

}

Invoke-Sqlcmd  @params
```

I need the ability to do it with Active Directory. I have read a few articles on how to connect with active directory as long as you specify it on the connection string (Context of C#) Using ODBC connection or other data sources. Since Powershell is based on .Net; this should be do-able..

```
    $ConnString = "DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;SERVER=xxxxx.database.windows.net;DATABASE=DBName;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
    $Conn = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection($ConnString)
    $conn.open()
    $cmd = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand("select getdate() as X", $Conn)
    $data = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter($cmd)
    $dt = new-object System.Data.DataColumn
    $data.Fill($dt) 
    $Conn.Close()

#`server=Server;database=Database;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;`
```

The objective of trying to use Active Directory is that, within Paas, only AD Accounts can Add other AD accounts. I want to be able to add other accounts with method rather than logging in the Azure portal and adding an AD account manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Azure AD account to login Azure SQL database(Paas) by using Azure Active Directory Authentication. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication).

Note: Local domian AD user does not support this.

You could use following script to login with Azure AD authentication.

```
#You admin Azure AD user name
$Username = "shuitest@*****.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = "********"
$Database = "testg"
$Server = 'test.database.windows.net'
$Port = 1433
$cxnString = "Server=tcp:$Server,$Port;Database=$Database;Authentication=Active Directory Password;UID=$UserName;PWD=$Password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
$query = "select count(*) from dbo.Authors"
$cxn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($cxnString)
$cxn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $cxn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$cxn.Close()
```

Comment: It throws an exception for me: WSTrust response does not have recognized SAML assertion

Answer (score 2):

The following sample shows how to invoke Add-AzureAccount without the popup dialog:

```
$username = "someorgid@orgaccount.com"
$password = "Pa$$w0rd" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password 
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $credential
```

Answer (score 0):

AAD does not / can not parse Kerbs tokens.  In order to get integrated auth to work from your desktop, you need to have ADFS (or similar) in your environment.  That way your desktop will authenticate against AAD, redirect to ADFS, and your kerbs token will be recognized.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication for more information.

Answer (score 0):

this now works for me in the connection string instead of user and pass

Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your query you might have to use `$cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` for example

```
$query = 'select @@version'
$cxn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($cxnString)
$cxn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $cxn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
$cmd.ExecuteScalar()
$cxn.Close()
```